# JS Json code not outputing data on view source

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, flickr

I am using the following code on my page:

```
<script>$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
function(data){
$.each(data.items, function(i,item){
$("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#gallery").wrap("<a rel='external' href='" + item.media.m + "'></a>");



if ( i == 20 ) return false;
});
});</script>
```

When I look at the page source I don't see the image tags, just the script and I have added a jS lib so that the images will popup when clicked on.

This is not happening BUT when I get the image code added by jquery and paste it directly to my page and save it, it then works perfectly.

Does anyone have a clue why this would happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fiddle works just fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/NEFma/

You can't see the image tags in the view source on most browsers.

(However, if you are using chrome you should be able to -- right click on a cat and say inspect element)

Answer (score 1):

View source shows you the source of the original html file, it does not update when javascript updates the DOM. Most browsers have some form of tool that allows you to inspect the current state of the DOM, such as the inspector in webkit browsers or firebug in firefox.